# Prolog if-else conditionals

Tags: prolog

I'm new to prolog and I'm trying to implement a BST. The BST is implicit in the form of `node(X,L,R)` with `X` as an positive integer, `L` the left child tree, `R` the right child tree, and `leaf` as the base case.

One feature of this BST is to be able to search for an element of the tree. `elem(Bst,Elem)` succeeds if `Elem` is an element of `Bst`, false otherwise.

Example:

```
?- elem(leaf,_).
false.

?- elem(node(3,node(2,leaf,leaf),node(5,leaf,leaf)),2).
true.
```

My attempt at implementation:

```
elem(leaf,Elem) :-
  false.

elem(Bst,Elem) :-
  Bst = node(X,L,R),
  Elem > 0,
  (Elem is X ->
    true;
    elem(L,Elem),
    elem(R,Elem)).
```

But I'm too sure about this b/c I'm not sure what happens with the `if-else` conditional. The idea is obviously to succeed with `true` if `Elem is X` is `true`, but since prolog doesn't "return" anything, I'm not sure what would happen.

Is this right? How do I fix it? What could I do better?

Comment: You're not sure if what you wrote works? Did you try it? You don't need `elem(leaf, _) :- false.` because `elem(leaf, _)` should naturally fail as long as you don't have a rule or fact that causes it to succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need conditionals in Prolog too often. This problem for example could be solved like this:

```
bst_member(node(X, L, R), Elem) :-
    compare(Order, X, Elem),
    bst_member_1(Order, Elem, L, R).

bst_member_1(>, Elem, L, _) :- bst_member(L, Elem).
bst_member_1(=, _, _, _). % Found it!
bst_member_1(<, Elem, _, R) :- bst_member(R, Elem).
```

This works with anything, not just integers or positive integers. If you indeed have only integers, you can use `library(clpfd)` and the predicate `zcompare/3` instead of `compare/3`. But this is beyond the scope of what you are currently asking.

Comment: are the `<,>,=` equalities atoms in this case?

Comment: @thestateofmay Try `?- atom(>).` on the toplevel and see what you get :-) but yes, it seems they are. I just know that it works like this. If you want to know how exactly Prolog is parsed you should read the parser of your implementation :-( I also rememer that "The Craft of Prolog" contains a reference Prolog parser written in Prolog, if you are that interested.

Answer (score 0):

```
elem(node(Elem,_,_),Elem).

elem(node(X,L,R),Elem):- 
    dif(X,Elem),
    (elem(L,Elem);elem(R,Elem)).
```

Try this, It's as simple as I check if equal, if not, search left and right

Comment: Try `dif(X, Elem)` instead

Comment: Why is that? Will something in the logic change? I agree that it makes it easier to read, but does it have another effect?

Comment: See [tag:prolog-dif]

Comment: Looks like it is better with variables, although I didn't encounter a case that fails with my approach, but I will change it just in case ;)

Comment: `X \= a, X = b` fails, but `X = b, X \= a` succeeds. But with `dif/2` both are the same.

Comment: This solution does not take advantage of the fact that this is a BST.

Comment: You are correct, But I thought of writing a simple code to be understood rather than writing 2 cases of checking if value is smaller than or equal etc..

Comment: Yeah I get it but searching the whole tree even though it is a binary search tree is kind of wrong